# Refer to JSON child data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the below JSON returned from a DB. How do I refer to the element STOCK without specifying by name? I know I can do NewDataSet.STOCK but this JSON is dynamic.

I have tried NewDataSet[1] but it doesn't like that. Is there a way to refer to it?

```
{
    "NewDataSet": {
            "@": {
                "xmlns": "STOCK"
            },
            "STOCK": {
                "STOCK_GROUP": "Default",
                "STOCK_CODE": "qwertyuiop",
                "FEEDER_OR_TRAY_NUMBER": "1",
                "ENABLED": "Enabled",
                "WEIGHT": "1",
                "PRIORITY": "0",
                "STOCK_TYPE": "Paper",
                "STOCK_ID": "1",
                "VALID_FROM": "1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                "VALID_TO": "1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                "STOCK_IMAGE": {}
            }
        }
    }
```

**Here is an example of 2 or more rows:**:

```
{
    "NewDataSet": {
        "@": {
            "xmlns": "SECURITY_GROUPS"
        },
        "SECURITY_GROUPS": [
            {
                "GROUP_ID": "100",
                "NAME": "Administrators",
                "DESCRIPTION": "Access to all aspects of system"
            },
            {
                "GROUP_ID": "101",
                "NAME": "Operators",
                "DESCRIPTION": "users of device"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I then run this javascript:

```
$.each(data[0], function(key, value) {
    columnArr.push({"sTitle" : key});
});

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var innerArr = [];
    $.each(value, function(innerKey, innerValue) {
        innerArr.push(innerValue);
    });
    alueArr.push(innerArr);
});
```

Comment: You can only iterate over the objects properties then, after you parsed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the elements in a associative array like this:

```
for (var key in NewDataSet) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // key holds 'STOCK', obj[key] holds the data you are after
    }
}
```

Looking at the data, they kind of suggest what you should actually do is to explicitly retrieve '@' and then check 'xmlns' in there to understand what key you should be searching for...

--- edit after your edits it's clearer that this is what you need

```
var tableName = NewDataSet['@'].xmlns;
var rows = NewDataSet[tableName];
// enforce array
if (!rows.hasOwnProperty('length')) { rows = [rows]; }
```

Comment: Wow! That is amazing, I thought it might have been a stringify bug so was going down that route. Didn't think to try and enforce an array because I didnt know how to check if was one.

Comment: You can also use `rows instanceof Array` according to [Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html).  Chances of a name collision with `length` are low since the fields are in all caps so your way will likely work.

Comment: I've just spotted that if a table doesn't have data there is no @ property. Is there a way I can detect if its there?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use array indexes to refer to an object's properties.  Will the `@` property always contain the name?  If so you can use that:

```
var prop = NewDataSet["@"]["xmlns"];
NewDataSet[prop]["WEIGHT"] // equal to "1"
```

Comment: @ will always contain the name but if there are numerous stock records would NewDataSet[prop] return all rows so I can loop over them?

Comment: If you are returning 1...n rows from a database then "STOCK" should be an array.  You could access a row with `NewDataSet[prop][0]`

Comment: See updated question. Your approach works on SECURITY_GROUPS but not on STOCK. I see it gets the data but my loops are failing

Comment: var data = NewDataSet["STOCK"]; data[0] is undefined but fine if I use SECURITY_GROUPS

Comment: That's because `NewDataSet["STOCK"];` is not an array, it is an object.  The server is generating different code if you only have one row.  You should always return an array, even if it only has a single element so you can avoid any "special cases."

Comment: My server is sending JSON.stringify(result); and the client is then doing $.parseJSON(data); if I can't fix it is there a way to determine the difference between an array of data and just a single element?

Comment: see my answer below for a way to enforce an array.

Answer (score 0):

How dynamic will it be? Will one property always be "@", and then there will always be one (and only one) other property that is the one you want? If so, the jQuery `$.each` method would work:

```
$.each(NewDataSet,function(index,value){
    if(index !== '@'){
        //do your stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: There will always be @ but there may be numerous stock rows

Comment: I want to use $.each after getting my data however using var data = NewDataSet["STOCK"]; $.each(data[0],function(index,value){}); fails